# Is there a difference between git add -a and git add -A?

Tags: command-line, git

I've been using the former, `git add -a` forever.

Given that we mainly use git in a case-sensitive context (Linux or Cygwin), I'm surprised I've got away with it, as I read from the help:

```
$ git add -h
usage: git add [<options>] [--] <pathspec>
...
    -A, --all             add changes from all tracked and untracked files
```

... is this assuming that lower-case "a" stands for "--all" or something like that? Or is it being unusually permissive in terms of case?

Or is it something else entirely?

Comment: I found this with all the relevant parameters? https://devdocs.io/git/git-add




-A
--all
--no-ignore-removal
Update the index not only where the working tree has a file matching <pathspec> but also where the index already has an entry. This adds, modifies, and removes index entries to match the working tree.

If no <pathspec> is given when -A option is used, all files in the entire working tree are updated (old versions of Git used to limit the update to the current directory and its subdirectories).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither; the option (one-dash lowercase `a`) doesn't exist at all.

```
$ git --version
git version 2.23.0

$ git add -a
error: unknown switch `a'
usage: git add [<options>] [--] <pathspec>...
```

However, if you use an option with *two* dashes, any unambiguous prefix will be automatically expanded to the full option, as is standard GNU getopt() behavior. For example, all these commands actually specify the same `--all` option:

```
git add --a
git add --al
git add --all
```

(Similarly `--v` or `--verb` would get auto-expanded to `--verbose`, even if they don't exist as standalone options. However, `--ignore` would complain about an ambiguous match.)

There is also `git commit -a`, which is mostly equivalent to `git add --update` before commit.

Comment: Thanks.  This is mighty strange. I'm sure I've always used "-a". But, now I try it, of course it fails with "unknown switch".

Comment: Well, you can probably check `~/.bash_history`. Meanwhile I should check git.git in case the option used to exist but has been removed from the latest version...

Comment: Had a look: "git add -A" all the time.  I'm quite clearly losing what few marbles I had left.  I plan to delete this question.

Comment: Oh ... can't now delete because you answered.